# How to add emojies in vscode using debian linux?

Tags: javascript, linux, visual-studio-code, debian

How to add emojies in vscode using debian linux?
I tried ctrl + . but its not working,
also I tried win+ . but not working, should i need to install external library, or some blugin in vscode to add emojies in my code ?

and what if i need to write it in terminal ?

Comment: You can use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `u` + `Unicode of emoji` (For example; `283b` Unicode for the smile emoji)

Comment: what are you looking for? some kind of inline popup menu like there is in Windows? Some kind of external emoji palette application / window like in macOS or Ubuntu? Ex. Why can't you just do the stupid but kind of obvious thing and copy and paste from somewhere else like a web search?